# Build multilevel array from single relation table

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, dictionary

I have an excel file with two columns. The first column (A) has parents and the second has children (B). A row has the information, what the parent of a child is.

```
Parent  |   Child
1       |   2
1       |   4
1       |   6
2       |   3
4       |   2
4       |   3
3       |   5
```

I now want to build a multilevel array that has i tree structure.
What I want to achieve is, that I later want to give a parent (e.g. 2) and receive a list of levels and children and their level.
The global goal should be: I want to know, if I move two top level parents, have they similar childs? This should be possible from whatever level.

Comment: Item 1 has Item 2 as a child.  Item 2 has a Item 1 as a child.  Item 2 has a itself as a child,  This is not a tree structure.

Comment: BTW: The plural of child is children. If English spelling was consistent how would we make it difficult to learn.   What does: "I want to know, if I move two top level parents, have they similar childs? This should be possible from whatever level."? What does moving have to do with having similar children?  How do you reconcile "top level" and "any level"?

Comment: Agree with @TonyDallimore. Can't understand what you want to achieve. Maybe a picture of the desired result would help.

Comment: Thanks you for your answers. The real example ist: I have some CAD assemblies that I want to import to a PDM system. I can't import two parants that have equal children. So I have this table. @Tony Dallimore: Item 1 has children 2,4,6. Item 4 has children 2 and 3. Item 3 has child 5. This IS a tree structure.

Comment: Comment of 4 hours ago replaced to add missing word.  Your table does not confirm to any assemblies known to me. If 1 is a car and 2 is a wheel then a wheel can be a child of a car but a car cannot be a child of a wheel. A wheel cannot be a child of a wheel. You need to explain what real world components can match your table

Comment: I removed the line that said 1 is a child of 2 - you are right!

Comment: I do not known what PDM system you are using but I would view a system crashing because a component is being used as part of a previously loaded assembly as a major bug. If the supplier could not fix the bug quickly, I would reject the system as unfit for purpose and demand my money back.

Comment: Suppose I want to import 1. It has children 2, 4 and 6.  I import 2 and then its child 3. I cannot import 4 because its two children have already been imported. Perhaps I should not have imported 2 as a child of 1 but as a child of 4.  How do you handle situations like this?

Comment: If the PDM system database is empty, user A can import the subset of the data that is useful to them.  The data useful to user B does not conflict with user A's data so user B's data can be imported as well.  However, the data useful to user C does conflict with user A's data but not user B's. Do you need a system that warns user C that they must wait for user A to delete their data?

Comment: How do you handle the import and deletion of data?  Does this Excel worksheet hold the authoritative definition of the relationship between parents and their children?

Comment: Tony Dallimore - show me a PDM system which can handle importing a physically exact same CAD file twice at the same time without showing any errors.

Comment: If a comment is posted against your question, you are told. If a comment is posted against my answer, I am told. But if you post a comment against your question then nobody is told unless you place an @ before their name. I checked your question for some days after 1Dec16 in case you did not know this but I had given up before 12Dec16 so it was only today that I noticed your comment.

Comment: I am not an expert on PDM systems. However, the basis of good design is that components are reused where possible. How can you version manage your systems if you cannot record that component X is used in A, B and C?  What if component X has several versions? Can you record that A contains version 1 of X and B contains version 2 of X?  My interest in Product Data Management systems is the version control of software. I have hundreds of routines in tens of products. I fail to see how a PDM system with the deficiencies you describe would help.

Comment: My interpretation is that you have to live with your PDM system and you are using Excel to handle what it does not. Following the comment in which I criticise your PDM system, I ask three questions to help me understand what you are doing with Excel. Are these questions sensible or have I misunderstood what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

You do not give enough information about your requirement to give a definitive answer so here are some ideas.

My first attempt at a structure would be:

```
  | Parents | Children |
1 | 2       | 2  4  6  |
2 | 1  2  4 | 1  2  3  |
3 | 2  4    | 5        |
4 | 1       | 2  3     |
5 | 3       |          |
6 | 1       |          |
```

That is, for each of the items, I would have a list of parents and a list of children.  I would consider the effort to create this structure and consider how easily I could answer required questions from this structure.  This was not a difficult structure to build manually so should not be a difficult structure for a macro to build.  You want to know if two items have the same children. This can be determined quickly by examining the lists of children for the two items.

You would need a full review against your planned uses for this structure.  However, for the moment this structure looks satisfactory.

In your table, the identifiers for the items are the numbers 1 to 6 without gaps.  If this is representative of the real data, I would probably define a user type and hold the data as an array:

```
Type utItem
  Parents() As Long
  Children() as Long
End Type

Dim Items() as utItem
```

If the real identifiers are strings or scattered numbers, I believe I would go for a dictionary.  For each entry, the key would be the identifier and the item would be a pair of arrays: one for parents and one for children.

**Proposal 2**

The additional information suggests a structure like this is what you require:

```
Prnt | D?| Children
 ABC |   | BBC  BBD  FGI  FGJ  KLM 
 STU | D | BBC  BBD  FGI  FGJ  KLM
 GHI | D | BBC  BBD  FGI  FGJ  KLM
 ABD |   | BBC  FGJ
 FGH | D | BBC  FGI  FGJ  KLM
 ABE |   | BBC  FGI  FGJ  KLM
```

The three letter identifiers represent filename.  The real filenames will be longer but that does not matter.

For each parent, the children have been listed in alphabetic order.  The list has then been sorted by the identifiers of the children with the sequence of parents being unimportant.  For example, STU and GHI have the same children.  If the list was sorted by children then parent, the GHI row would come first.  If it were important for the GHI row to come first, you need to add this requirement.

A D in the second column indicates that the row has the same children as the previous row.

There is nothing in this list to indicate if ABC, for example, has its own parent or parents.  Such information may be helpful during the building of this list but it is not needed once the list is complete.

You want to load this data to a PDM system.  You can add item ABC and its children to the PDM system but you cannot add STU because it has the same children.  I do not understand.  You cannot just ignore item STU because it may have parents which will reference it.

The loading of data to the PDM system will be a one-time exercise.  Creating the above structure cannot be impossibly slow but does not have to be lightning fast.  For example, five minutes might be wonderful, forty-five minutes would be acceptable but twenty hours would not be acceptable.

Comment: Hey, the real identifiiers are strings (filenames) and the list is a list of 337.000 rows and the resulting dictionary/array/list could have up to 15 levels.

Comment: Your help is amazing. I need to explain "equal children" more specific: If ABC has KLM as a child (on level 4) and FGH has KLM as child (on level 3) they have an equal child and can't be imported. The structure doesn't need to be the same. If a minimum of one child is equal, the two assemblies can't be imported at the same time. To understand why: If you import two equal files at the same time, which one is the correct one? The import procedure crashes. One should be imported first, the second one should be reused from the PDM system as a single source of truth.

Comment: You will have to include a lot more information in your question if I am to understand your requirement and offer constructive advice.  In your example data 1 is a child of 2 and 2 is a child of 1 and 2.  What real world items do 1 and 2 represent?  2 is a child of 1, 2 and 4.  If you can only import 2 as a component once, which of 1, 2 and 4 do you import?  What is to happen to the other two parents?  Importing 1 as the ultimate parent seem would sensible but, if you cannot import two of its children, how is that possible?

Comment: We have several users that import the data. But if a user imports a parent as any child that an other is is importing at the same time the import crashes. So the first user has to import tha parent with all children and after that the second user can start. I will found out parents that can be imported parallely at the same time without crashes because they have not one single equal child in what ever level. Sorry for the loss of information.